# Scrapy Flight Search

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm trying to use Scrapy in Python to run a flight search on some flights and then export it to a csv. This is just for fun as I learn more about Scrapy.

Here is what I have

```
 from scrapy.item import Item, Field
 from scrapy.http import FormRequest
 from scrapy.spider import Spider


 class DeltaItem(Item):
     title = Field()
     link = Field()
     desc = Field()


 class DmozSpider(Spider):
     name = "delta"
     allowed_domains = ["delta.com"]
     start_urls = ["http://www.delta.com"]

def parse(self, response):
    yield FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                    formname='flightSearchForm',
                                    formdata={'departureCity[0]': 'JFK',
                                              'destinationCity[0]': 'SFO',
                                              'departureDate[0]': '07.20.2013',
                                              'departureDate[1]': '07.28.2013'},
                                    callback=self.parse1)

def parse1(self, response):
    print response.status
```

When I run it it returns blank.

Thanks

Comment: Ok im not sure what you mean exaclty, Im very new to python and scrapy. Is there something I'm missing in another file?

Comment: Will you please give me your scrapy log?I mean all your output when you run the `scrapy crawl delta` command.

Comment: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7 /Users/AlexCohen/PycharmProjects/examplespider/Craigs.py

Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 0):

Tested in my spider and give me the log

> 2015-04-17 11:29:28+0800 [delta] DEBUG: Crawled (200) http://www.delta.com> (referer: None)
>   2015-04-17 11:29:28+0800 [delta] DEBUG: Crawled (200) http://www.delta.com/air-shopping/findFlights.action> (referer: http://www.delta.com)
>   200  #**This is the print of parse1**
>   2015-04-17 11:29:28+0800 [delta] INFO: Closing spider (finished)